# Upgrade to tensorflow2.0 alpha with some cuda troubles

Tags: tensorflow, cuda

I have already use tensorflow1.12 and Cuda9.0 in my Windows computer.
Today, I want to upgrade tensorflow to 2.0 alpha, so I create a new environment via Anaconda and pip install tensorflow-gpu 2.0 alpha. As I know that cuda 10.0 is required while I don't want to uninstall my existed 9.0, so I try `conda install cudatoolkit cudnn`. It is shown that cudatoolkit: 10.0.130-0 and  cudnn:       7.3.1-cuda10.0_0 are both downloaded automatically.

Then, I try tensorflow2.0.
`import tensorflow` does not raise errors.
However, when I use `x=tf.constant([1])`, it raises that

```
cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

I think the problem is that my tensorflow2.0 can't find the downloaded cudatoolkit 10.0, although they are in the same anaconda environment. So how can I solve it

Comment: The error message is extremely straightforward and literal. The GPU driver version you have installed does not support CUDA 10. You need to upgrade it

Comment: yes, you are right, I solve it by upgrate the GPU version. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily solved by upgrading my GPU driver version to the newest.

Comment: Please remember to come back and accept your answer in a few days so this question falls off the unanswered list